# limit log size for snap application (VLC)

Tags: snap, vlc, systemd-journald

vlc has a bug due to which it can generate gigabytes of logs in syslog and journalctl (12GB and 4GB). And because of the nature of journalctl, there is no way to clear the log of such garbage. But journalctl using logNamespace can limit the log size for the application. But with snap, things get even more complicated...
I'm looking for a way to split and limit the log for individual snap applications. Thanks.